# black wire coming into house?

Tags: wiring

I recently was looking around my house and finally realized the black wires (with some pins to help secure them to the side of the house accordingly) that were running here and there on my house that were going through the wall were my electrical outlets.

I have to ask, is this a common practice and should I try to do something to change or fix this?

I always had the understanding it (the electrical wires) should have been inside the walls or on the inside of the house.

Did I just buy the house without realizing whoever initially installed the wiring just did the cheap-thing?

Is this compliant with safety code? I'm in Washington State, USA.

Thanks for feedback.

Comment: is there anything printed on the black wires?

Comment: Please add a photo to make your question much more clear.

Comment: "Black wires"? Are you sure these are not cable TV wires? Are you in a rural area? Did you get an inspection before you bought this house? Where is the electric meter and the electrical panel?

Comment: Yes, these are black wires directly connected to my walls looked like it was drilled or poked through then filled in with a rubber clear substance with the wire I think.  I will add a picture probably by the end of the week (too busy to add pictures right now.) I am in semi-rural area... house 10-15 minutes walking distance from elementary school.

Comment: I have to ask... why is proximity to the local elementary school considered relevant information?

Comment: Jim Stewart asked me if I was in a rural area... (would a school being nearby be considered rural?)    I got a VA inspection before I purchased the house (I didn't hear any feedback about the cables)  The electric meter is on the side of the house and the panel is in the garage. (Yes the wires all link to the garage.)

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I would say they are Coaxial cable for cable or satellite tv. Some installers will put them next to an electrical outlet from the outside of the home because you will generally need to power a set-top box. If you look inside the house next to an electrical outlet, where this black wire seems to go into the house from outside, and have this or something similar:
[image]

then it is coaxial cable. Sometimes you will find just a short wire hanging out of the wall here. It is all up to the installer.